# Time zone for moment in a pod

Tags: timezone, openshift, momentjs, kubernetes-pod

I am using the `moment` package, in an OpenShift cluster pod, to get current time stamp. E.g.

```
let info.timestamp = moment().tz(moment.tz.guess()).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

How do I pass the time zone as an environment variable for the pod so that `moment().tz` does not evaluate to UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the following configuration ? You can set a specific timezone to pod using TZ environment variable.

```
$ oc set env <deployment controller resource type> <the resource name> TZ=<timezone>
```

For example, if you use test deploymentconfig for your pod, you can set "Tokyo/Asia" timezone for you pod as follows.

```
$ oc set env dc/test TZ=Asia/Tokyo
```